# Copy categories from parent configurable product to simple child product in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento, zend-framework

I need some advise on best way to archieve this programmatically.

The problem is that i have many configurable prodcuts (+20.000) which are allready in a category. All the simple underlaying child products are not in any category at all. I want all simple child products to inherit category from parent.

If configurable product "A" is in category called "Category A", all child products of product "A" should be included in "Category A".

This is going to used for an XML product feed, so i can not use anchor categories in Magento.

Any advise on how to archieve this, also considering the amounts of SKU's that needs to be updated in database?

Comment: How many configurables do you have ?

Answer (score 2):

We had this same problem. This query will fill in the gaps by grabbing each configurable product's children, and inserting a new category association for each one (one for each of the parent categories)

`INSERT IGNORE INTO catalog_category_product 
            (category_id, 
             product_id) 
SELECT ccp.category_id, 
       cpl.product_id 
FROM   catalog_product_super_link cpl 
       LEFT JOIN catalog_category_product ccp 
              ON ccp.product_id = cpl.parent_id 
WHERE  ccp.category_id IN (SELECT entity_id 
                           FROM   catalog_category_entity);`

Note: The WHERE clause at the end is to prevent foreign key errors.

Comment: `REPLACE` is not needed, use `INSERT IGNORE` instead.